# the powershell variable can't quote correctly in my script

Tags: powershell, shell, batch-file, cmd, ps1

greet !

at first i want to use powershell to generate a cmd  and put some command in it

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $ParameterName
)

cmd /c "start cmd /k " $ParameterName
```

it work well when i input some prompt without space  `& 'C:\ex-sys\Program files\dre\dre.ps1' tasklist`  ,but when the prompt with space like &

```
'C:\ex-sys\Program files\dre\dre.ps1' 'F:\git hub\yt-dlp\yt-dlp (27).exe'
```

it output in cmd

```
'F:\git' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
或批处理文件。
```

which mean 'F:\git' isn't command or any runable bat
,Apparently the cmd miss my quote in powershell
so is there anyway i could fix this problem

Comment: by the way when i use 'C:\ex-sys\exe\yt-dlp.lnk -help' it can open a cmd and run the command for me

Comment: So write `"$ParameterName"`.

Comment: Why are you running cmd twice? (in which case it should be ```cmd /c "start cmd /k "$ParameterName""```). Why not just use ```cmd /k "$ParameterName"```

Comment: @Compo, `cmd /k` executes _synchronously_, _in the same window_, i.e. takes over the interactive PowerShell session. I'm _guessing_ that the intent is to run the interactive `cmd.exe` session _asynchronously_, in a _new window_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

> `cmd /c "start cmd /k " $ParameterName`

with:

```bash
# Asynchronously starts an interactive cmd.exe session in a *new window*,
# in which the value of $ParameterName is executed as a command.
Start-Process cmd "/k `"$ParameterName`""
```

This avoids the unnecessary `cmd /c` call and uses *embedded* `"..."` quoting (`` `"...`" ``) around the value of `$ParameterName` to ensure that `cmd.exe` recognizes it a *single* argument even if it contains spaces.

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) is PowerShell's analog to `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command (and in PowerShell there's even a `start` *alias* for it).

Answer (score 1):

the following answer work well in the script ,if you want to add the parameter at the prompt using `& 'C:\ex-sys\Program files\dre\dre.ps1' '"F:\git hub\yt-dlp\yt-dlp (27).exe" --help'` ,double quote the paramter